# PyQT 4 Need help for adjusting to screen resolution

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt4

How can I make a window(without using a Layout) to resize depending on the screen resolution,and all the widgets resize with it?
Or how to have a scrollbar without using layouts?

Thanks !